# After Ubuntu One Music purchase, sync seems to be incomplete

Tags: ubuntu-one, 12.04, music

I'm having a bit of an issue.  I'm running the 12.04 beta, and I purchased a couple of albums from the Ubuntu One Music Store (running Rhythmbox).

Eight songs on each album downloaded and were synced, but there are a total of eight more songs that haven't downloaded.  In Rhythmbox, on the download page in the Ubuntu One Music Store, each song just says that it is queued, but I can't get them to download.

When viewing the Ubuntu One music folder in Nautilus, the folders all have green checkmarks indicating that the sync is complete, when it clearly isn't.

I've looked around a little bit, looking for some solutions, and found a suggestion to look at u1sdtool in a terminal and see what it was doing, and I got the following result:

```
u1sdtool --status
State: QUEUE_MANAGER
connection: With User With Network
description: processing the commands pool
is_connected: True
is_error: False
is_online: True
queues: IDLE
```

My first thought is to try and get that to not say "IDLE."  I've stopped and restarted u1sdtool, and my computer, with no success. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the download list says that the item is queued, that means that it hasn't yet been transferred from the store to your cloud storage.  Until that happens, there is nothing for the Ubuntu One client to copy to your local system (that is why `u1sdtool` says it is idle).  Once the song is transferred, your local client should start downloading it right away.

If the songs don't change from the "queued" state, consider filing a support request asking for it to be looked into:

https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

Remember to use the email address associated with your Ubuntu One account so that we can easily locate the problem songs.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, it seems that this was a case of me just being impatient.  When I woke up this morning, the remaining songs had all been transferred.  I don't know why it took a couple extra hours for it to go through, but all is well in the end.  Should I encounter more issues, like this, I'll contact support in the future.  Thanks for the information.